# Linear Transformation: Standard Matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

Suppose $T:R^2 \to R^3$ is a linear transformation such that:
$T([-1,0]) = (-1,1,0)$ and $T([2,-1]) = (3,-3,k)$.

Find the standard matrix $A$ for $T$. I have found this, it is

$$A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1
\\
-1 & 1
\\
0 & -k
\end{bmatrix}
$$
T is one-to-one only if k does not equal? (with proof). I have found this, $k$ cannot equal $0$, otherwise there exists a free variable.

When $k=0$, find all solutions to the equation $T(x)=0$. I end up with just the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1 &-1 \\0 & 0\\0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
How do I write all solutions? Can I just write the column vector $(x2, x2)$?

When $k=1$, find all solutions to the equation $T(x)=0$. I end up with the matrix:

$$\begin{bmatrix}1& 0\\0 & 1\\0& 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
 How do I write this as a general solution? Is it just the column vector $(0,0)$?

Comment: You may first want to write the standard basis vectors $e_{1} = \begin{bmatrix}1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $e_{2} = \begin{bmatrix}0\\1\end{bmatrix}$ as linear combinations of $\begin{bmatrix}-1\\0\end{bmatrix}$ and $\begin{bmatrix}2\\-1\end{bmatrix}$ . Then compute $T(e_{1})$ and $T(e_{2})$, and those will be the two columns of your matrix.

Comment: Very good so far!

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Thank you, can you help me with writing the general solutions for the last two? I think I have it , but I'm not sure.